# Loopback context returning null in afterRemote method

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I am newbie to **loopback**, I have written a function for **signup** and 
executing on **beforeRemote**. Here I can able to access loopback context. But after user created I am executing another function to send verification link using **afterRemote**, here loopback context returning null value.

```
function signup(){
  const lbCtx = LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext;
  const details = lbctx().get('details');
  //here it's working
}

function sendVerificationEmail(){
  const lbCtx = LoopBackContext.getCurrentContext;
  const details = lbctx().get('details');
  //here not working
}

Users.beforeRemote('create', (ctx) => signup(ctx));
Users.afterRemote('create', (ctx) => sendVerificationEmail(ctx));
```

can anyone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a documented issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1676#issuecomment-260088138) with the way the current context is handled in LoopBack.

Unfortunately it seems that the library they used to support this feature called [continuation-local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/continuation-local-storage) is not entirely reliable and sometimes the context is not properly passed around so you get a null value instead.

[There's a warning in the docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Using-current-context.html) stating this and links to different workarounds, since there's no unified solution yet.

Note: One issue I see with your code (although it might be a typo) is that in the `signup()` method you are doing `get()` instead of `set()`. Just in case you didn't notice.